# In Authorize.net CIM, why is my first transaction not showing in customer history?

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

In both sandbox and production environments, the first transaction received by the CIM through the authorize.net API is not listed in the customer history. However, all subsequent transactions are listed. Note that the first transaction can be found by searching the transaction ID but I am puzzled why it's not listed in the history.

For example:

- Customer profile id: 123546789
- The first transaction for this customer is: 987654321 but this transaction ID is not listed in the history
- Four transactions occurred for this customer after the first one and they are all listed in the history

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: This sounds like you should be contacting Authnet customer support as this would be unusual behavior.

Comment: @JohnConde Agreed. I have submitted a support ticket but have not received a reply so I thought I'd see if anyone has seen similar behavior.

Comment: If you do get a reply please post the solution as answer so others with this same issue can more easily find it

Comment: @JohnConde - I heard back from Authorize.net. They claim this is expected behavior but did not elaborate. I find this hard to believe and may submit another ticket for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the update and please do follow up on this. Maybe @rhldr can offer some insight for us as an answer to this question? I am going to add the authorize.net tag which I know he follows and maybe he'll see this question.

Comment: Was this first transaction created using a customer profile, or did you create a customer profile as part of the first transaction?  I also assume you submitted actual customer profile and transaction ids to support in your ticket.

Comment: @rhldr This pattern occurs when the customer profile is created as part of the first transaction. Yes, I submitted those details as part of my request.

Comment: @rhldr I have heard back from Authorize.net and they now say that this type of transaction should show in the customer history. They recommended I contact their live support so they can look at the transactions in production. I will report back when I know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke with the authorize.net Live Support Team and we examined production accounts where this occurred. They had to go into their internal documentation to find the answer.

This is expected behavior due to order of operations. Meaning, when the transaction is sent at the same time the customer profile is being created, the transaction is first run and verified prior to the profile being created so they don't end up creating a profile that is not going to be used.

For this reason, the transaction will never be tied back to the customer history because the profile didn't exist when the transaction was run. They understand this is confusing and suggested submitting a request to rectify this in future versions of the API.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I think this is the only place on the Internet that contains this information.

Comment: Update. Because I need to tie all transactions to a customer I ended up breaking out the calls. First I create a customer with a payment profile THEN I have a separate call to charge the newly created profile. It’s inconvenient but fixes the problem.